# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON, Getting HTML response instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, jsx

Context: I have been working on a project (called Music Master) on which i have to access details of artist from developer.spotify.com.
The following is the code snippet:

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?';
    const FETCH_URL = `${BASE_URL}q=${this.state.query}&type=artist&limit=1`;
    console.log('FETCH_URL', FETCH_URL);
    fetch('FETCH_URL', {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            "Content-Type" : "Application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer BQDyac2glKnbstiG79UKzKSReNbsWa_hEKlOWAZtXaFZpfx8ZibluRUmBHHO12CjLMJv3KBaKTZqUKJReA11_ItrYIkr3CmnUi6ykUD7J0gZk9pKzxjz02j4byQfSa6s7Y08OMNzugFffYc68tzZiGSDp9vB80eiiIod_igAH8ZxbPBUMsRH3pbiMY8tnJpeXmk"              }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        const artist = json.artists.items[0];
        console.log('artist', artist);
        this.setState({artist});
    });
```

When running the code i am getting the above error, i have been researching on this issue for quite a while on the internet and found out that i have to add the header part in the fetch() but even after adding the header part i am getting the error.

I am not able to understand even after passing the token also why am i getting HTML response instead of JSON.

I am really new and this is my first project and hence i am not able to understand what is the internal functioning behind this.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the response? It might be an error page or the like...

Comment: Yeah, so what is happening is that when i am opening the link, it is showing ERROR 401, "message": "No token provided", but i am providing token.

Comment: Why are you adding a content-type header? There's no _content_

Comment: @Phil, i found the part when was researching for the same error and added, i just removed it but the still receiving the error!

Comment: It seems Spotify uses "missing token" to mean that the token isn't sufficiently authorized, as on the SO question [Spotify API get user saved tracks error 401 missing token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70688601/1426891).

Comment: I didn't say it was your problem, I only asked why you had added it

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

> A `fetch()` promise does not reject on HTTP errors (404, etc.).

It's not ideal to return HTML when you pass an Accept header for json, but errors generally aren't ideal in the first place. You'll probably want to check that the [`response.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) is 200 before trying to parse as JSON.

Comment: I am receiving 404 on checking response.status

Comment: @yash Incidentally, since `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search` returns a JSON response here in my Chrome address bar, maybe it's your own server that is returning an HTML 404 page. You can check your browser's developer tools, but it does look like your `fetch` call is asking for the quoted URL `'FETCH_URL'`, not the constant `FETCH_URL`.

Comment: So, the error i am being shown, is system (server) specific?

Comment: @yash I don't know; I can't see the error and I don't know which server you're using to serve your app. All I know is that Spotify seems to appropriately return JSON even in its error messages, and that your code in your question looks like it's requesting a page called "FETCH_URL" (because you used quotes) instead of the Spotify URL you constructed.